# How to reduce elements of objects in array with Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, merge, reduce

I have list like:

```
[{"center":"LFEEAPP","cause":"S ","total":66},{"center":"LFFFAD","cause":"S","total":78},{"center":"LFMMAPP","cause":"C","total":143},{"center":"LFMMAPP","cause":"T","total":0}]
```

Now, I want to add all the values ​​of the centers which include: 'APP' and 'AD' with the reduce method and changed the label just 'APP', so with this example of list, I created pipe must return:
APP: 209 (total) and LFFFAD :78

**the pipe :**

```
export class MergeCentresAppPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(listCount: ListCount[]): ListCount[] {
    const totalCenterApp = listCount
      .filter(count => count.center.includes('APP'))
      .map(count => count.total)
      .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0);

    const centerApp: ListCount = {
      center: 'APP',
      cause: '',
      total: totalTimeCenterApp,
    };

    const centerMerged = listCount.filter(count => !count.center.includes('APP'));
    centreMerged.push(centerApp);

    return centerMerged;
  }
}
```

How can I add 'AD' string to the filter to get :
**APP: 287** (APP: 209 + LFFFAD: 78)
Thank you for your help

Comment: It is unclear what is problematic. Passing 'AD' as a parameter? Adding a condition to filter? Also your description of the desired output is unclear

Comment: yes, I want add 'AD' to the filter

Comment: I tried to do:
```.filter(count => count.center.includes('APP' || 'AD'))```

Comment: You mean like this: `.filter(count => count.center.includes('APP') || count.center.includes('AD'))`?

Comment: I think , I get the solution:
```.filter(count=> countcenter.includes('APP') || ( count.center.includes('AD')))```

Comment: Looks good to me - we have identical code :)

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MergeCentresAppPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(listCount: ListCount[]): ListCount[] {
    const totalCenterApp = listCount
      .filter(count => count.center.includes('APP') || count.center.includes('AD')))
      .map(count => count.total)
      .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0);

    const centerApp: ListCount = {
      center: 'APP',
      cause: '',
      total: totalTimeCenterApp,
    };

    const centerMerged = listCount.filter(count => !count.center.includes('APP') && !count.center.includes('AD'));
    centreMerged.push(centerApp);

    return centerMerged;
  }
}
```